# Mysql Code To Mark New And Duplicate Values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, select-query

I have a mysql table (shown below) with some values, I need to get the new values and duplicate values

I tried `SELECT *,COUNT(SerialNumber) FROM config_log GROUP BY SerialNumber`;

But it return only the duplicate count. How to find this ???

Thank You

**Table :**

```
   Id   SerialNumber   ConfigDate  ProductId
    ---+--------------+-----------+---------
    1    11111          2018-12-22    1
    2    22222          2018-12-22    2
    3    33333          2018-12-22    3
    4    11111          2018-12-23    1
```

**Product Table :**

```
 ProductId    Name
-----------+------
  1           a
  2           b
  3           c
```

**Expected Result**

```
Id   SerialNumber   ConfigDate   Type      Name
---+--------------+------------+----------+-------
1    11111          2018-12-22   New          a
2    22222          2018-12-22   New          b
3    33333          2018-12-22   New          c
4    11111          2018-12-23   Duplicate    a
```

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: Server version: 10.1.28-MariaDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=cb25266d766681f323e7cee304b6179f)**

```
select id,SerialNumber,ConfigDate, case when num=1 then 'New' else 'Duplicate' end as  Type,
productid,name
from
(
SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @SerialNumber = SerialNumber THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS num,
    @SerialNumber:=SerialNumber as PSerialNumber, id, SerialNumber,ConfigDate,productid,name
FROM
    t1 left join product on productid=pid ,(SELECT @SerialNumber:=0,@row_number:=0) AS t
order by SerialNumber
)A
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. its Working, I need to join another table with this how its possible ???

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A, could you please add that table to your quesiton

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A, check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=cb25266d766681f323e7cee304b6179f

Comment: Thanks Bro Its Working. Thanks You for the support.

Answer (score 1):

the following mysql query will produce the expected result

```
SELECT cl.*, 
       IF (cl.id = (SELECT Min(id) 
                    FROM   `config_log` 
                    WHERE  cl.serialnumber = serialnumber 
                    ORDER  BY id ASC), 'NEW', 'DUPLICATE') AS type, 
       p.name 
FROM   `config_log` AS `cl` 
       INNER JOIN products AS p 
               ON p.id = cl.productid
```

Tested on mysql Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: Thanks Bro Its Working

Comment: how to write where condition like type='NEW' or type='DUPLICATE'

Comment: you can add having in end like this " HAVING type = 'DUPLICATE' "..

It may sound not logical to add having without group by but its works .. not the best solution ... its better to redo the query if you have different requirements

Answer (score 1):

for filtering the result you can use having like this

```
SELECT cl.*, 
       IF (cl.id = (SELECT Min(id) 
                    FROM   `config_log` 
                    WHERE  cl.serialnumber = serialnumber 
                    ORDER  BY id ASC), 'NEW', 'DUPLICATE') AS type, 
       p.name 
FROM   `config_log` AS `cl` 
       INNER JOIN products AS p 
               ON p.id = cl.productid 
HAVING type = 'DUPLICATE'
```